# Tetanus shot, Typhoid shot/vaccine

Tags: word-usage

I read somewhere:

> Get a Tetanus shot.....

Does "Tetanus shot" mean "Tetanus Vaccine "?

And can "shot" be used for other vaccines as well, like "Typhoid", "Pneumonia" etc.

> Get a Typhoid shot.

Or

> Get a Typhoid vaccine.

If both "shot" and "vaccine" are interchangeable, then what will be more likely to be used by a native, "shot" or "vaccine"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shot basically means an injection (of any kind, not just for vaccination) ([Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/injection)).

Vaccine is a general term for all types of vaccines; a shot is a vaccine given as an injection.

> Fainting after getting a shot: Fainting after any vaccine is more
>   common among adolescents. Sitting or lying down when getting a shot
>   and then for about 15 minutes after the shot can help prevent
>   fainting. ([CDC.gov](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/parents/protecting-children/years-11-12.html))
>
> Vaccination is the act of getting a vaccine, usually as a shot.
>   ([Vaccines.gov](https://www.vaccines.gov/basics))

Vaccines in the form of tablets are called oral vaccines and not shots.

> There are two vaccines to prevent typhoid. One is an inactivated
>   (killed) vaccine gotten as a shot. The other is a live, attenuated
>   (weakened) vaccine which is taken orally (by mouth). ([CDC.gov](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/hcp/vis/vis-statements/typhoid.html))

Comment: One tiny quibble: a **shot** is any type of medical injection, whether it's a vaccine or not.  You can get a Vitamin B-12 shot, for example, which is not a vaccine.

Comment: Yes, I updated.